# How to write dataframes with multiple types as a table in hdf5 files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, serialization, hdf5

I have multiple .csv files that have different data per column but are sorted by timestamp/DOY (ie: air temperature, air pressure, air density at 23:45, 11/25/2019). I would like to maintain this same layout when writing to a HDF5 table. However, when I write my dataframe objects to the .h5 file and use HDFViewer to visualize the data/tables, it shows as a bunch of hex and user-defined class names that I made. I have not tried retrieving/reading back what I have written to see if its correctly serialized, but that is what I'm working on right now to debug.

I am unfamiliar with HDF5 serialization and have ran into what I think is the problem I've been experiencing: the dataframe objects I am using to organize the data from .csv files treat each index/row/column as some arbitrary object type rather than each particular table value being classified as a native type (I only have strings and floats in the tables....), and I receive a "TypeError: object of type int has no len()" when I try to write to the HDF5. I have found that there apparently was a bug with this? I have made sure I have no type casting errors in my code and the error only occurs when I try to write my dataframe to the HDF5. Every example I've seen of writing dataframe to HDF5 seems to only have integers or some homogenous native type throughout the whole data table, so I am confused whether or not I am actually able to format the data how I want.

| date | timestamp | sonic_temperature | air_temperature | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/25/2019 | 19:45 | 301.676 | 275.8182577 |  |
| 11/25/2019 | 20:00 | 301.687 | 275.0586316 |  |
| 11/25/2019 | 20:15 | 301.708 | 275.4334489 |  |
| 11/25/2019 | 20:30 | NAN | NAN |  |

I was intending for the date and timestamp columns be stored as strings, whereas the other two columns be stored as floats, but all under the SAME table in the hdf5 group. However, the type according to however I serialized the dataframe and/or series object seems to say every value in the table is some sort of "object" (I think, not sure though....) and will not display any sort of table in HDFViewer. Perhaps I am going the wrong way about this. If doing this is too inconvenient and inefficient, is there some other way to serialize data from a .csv file with data formatted similar to the above table into a .h5 file while maintaining a table format? Keep in mind, the data is not sorted, so I have to read in multiple .csvs with multiple dates and timestamps (sometimes they're missing) and have to sync them up. I was thinking of maybe outputting the dataframes to .csv files and then reading them in again to some other more-easily-serializable object, but that seems like it could take up a lot of processing power and time...

I am not a programmer, or at least not a very experienced one, so I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the whole process and optimal ways to go about this. I am fine doing a lot of refactoring if there is a better way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Example of what I'm trying to do, (assuming dataframe method can use multiple types):

```
dataFrame = pandas.read_csv(inFile)
#then sort data based on DOY and sync based on timestamp...
UserClassObjs = [] #list of userClassObjects, one for each unique DOY

#Assume csv file has been sorted into multiple dataframes according to DOY
#keep track of DOY and append dataframe to userClassObjs

if dataFrame['date'][0] == UserClassObjs[i].date #something like that, paraphrasing....
    UserClassObjs[i].dataFrames.append(dataFrame)

#UserClassObjs has DOY, metadata that will be read in and matched according to DOY, and array of dataframe objects with corresponding DOY

for i, object in UserClassObject: #there is an array of UserClassObjects in the main file
 
object = UserClassObject[i].dataFrame #dataframe is stored in user defined class as an array of dataframe objects to make keeping track of DOY easier, there can be multiple dataframes for the same DOY
object.to_hdf(h5File, "{DOY}/graphs")
```

Here is the code I am working with, I know it's probably very poorly written... Again, I am not a programmer but perhaps there's some big things I can do differently:

csvParser.py

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from math import ceil
from time import strftime, gmtime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from numpy import array,dtype,genfromtxt
import h5py
import sys

#used to parse csv files into pandas dataframe objects for FCObject dataframe array

class csvParser:
    def __init__(self,fileNames):
        #fileNames is an array of fileNames
        self.parseInputFiles(fileNames)

    def parseInputFiles(self, fileNames):
        self.csvFiles = [] # all files with .csv extension 
        self.txtFiles = [] # all files with .txt extension for metadata
        for file in fileNames:
            try:
                if Path(file).suffix == ".csv":
                    self.csvFiles.append(file)
                elif Path(file).suffix == ".txt":
                    self.txtFiles.append(file)
                else:
                    print(''.join(file + " is neither a .txt or .csv file. This will not be used in parsing process"))
            except:
                print("Error when handling input files. File may be corrupt or not the correct extension...")
    
    def makeMetaDataObjects(self, inFile):
        # parse based on file name: DOYXXX_20YY_metadata.txt
        # add to array of metadata objects
            #tuple object with DOY,metadata
        metaData = 'Metadata: '
        with open(inFile, 'r') as fileObj:
            lines = fileObj.readlines()
            #print(lines)
            metaData = str(lines)
        temp = inFile.split('_')
        date = dt(month = int(temp[0]), day = int(temp[1]), year = int(temp[2])).date()
        date = date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
        self.metaDataObjects.append([date, metaData])
        

    def makeCSVObjects(self, inFile):
        #tempDataFrame is reading in ALL data from csv file as a dataframe object
        #tempColumnNames are each column according to dataframe object
        #dateIndexList is list of unique DOYs for each dataframe/csv file
        #inFile is stored as origin file
        #all above are stored as a tuple according to each file
        #   ex: csvObject[0] = dataframe, csvObject[1] = columnNames, csvObject[2] = dateIndexList, csvObject[3] = inFile (as a string)

        tempDataFrame = pd.read_csv(inFile)
        tempColumnNames = list(tempDataFrame.columns)
    
        #finds indices of all first occurrence/unique DOY in csv files
        tempList = []
        dateIndexList = []
        for i in range(len(tempDataFrame['date'])):
            if tempDataFrame['date'][i] not in tempList:
                tempList.append(tempDataFrame['date'][i])
                dateIndexList.append(i) #add 2 to get actual row number in csv file for debugging purposes...

        #to account for last set in csv
        if dateIndexList is not len(tempDataFrame.index):
            dateIndexList.append(len(tempDataFrame.index))

        self.csvObjects.append([tempDataFrame, tempColumnNames, dateIndexList, inFile])
        #for index, tuple in enumerate(self.csvObjects): #debugging statement
        #    print(tuple[3])
        
    def createDataFrames(self):
        #set up to sort data per day from .csv and .txt files
        self.csvObjects = []
        self.metaDataObjects = []
        self.subFrames = [] 
        self.DOY = [] #should have dates to corresponding subframes, from .csv files
        self.metaDataDOY = [] # in the event metaData dates are not present in subframes? from .txt files
        self.FCObjects = [] # data structure that will be serialized/pickled into hdf5 format


        for file in self.csvFiles:
            self.makeCSVObjects(file)
        for file in self.txtFiles:
            self.makeMetaDataObjects(file)
        for object in self.csvObjects:
            self.makeSubDataFrames(object)
        self.findDOY()
        self.appendToFCObject()
        self.exportFCObjects()
        #self.exportSubFrames() # debugging function to see output files as csv
            
    def makeSubDataFrames(self,csvObject): #add date to parameters and call function x many times as are in days???? and add to FCOobject array
        #makes a dataframe for every unique DOY to serialize into .h5 file
        #compiles all data for a DOY into one dataframe and appends to subframeList
        #   ex: csvObject[0] = dataframe, csvObject[1] = columnNames, csvObject[2] = dateIndexList
        rowTimeStamps = []
        rowNames = []
        #columnLength = 96 # 1440/15 = 96, 1440 minutes in a day divided by increments of 15 min
        for i in range(96):
            rowNames.append(i)
            rowTimeStamps.append(strftime("%#H:%M", gmtime(i * 900))) #gmtime takes input as seconds: interval of 15 minutes * 60 seconds
        
        #Write data to dataframe according to timestamps (some timestamps may not have data (NAN) and may start anywhere between 0:00-23:45 time)
        a = 0
        b = 1
        #a and b variables are used to find start and stop points from each DOY from the input file
        #ie: DOY data starts at index a and ends at index b
        for n in range(len(csvObject[2])-1):

            #initialize blank subframe (timestamps and column names but no data)
            tempFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns = csvObject[1], index=rowTimeStamps)
            for i in range(csvObject[2][a], csvObject[2][b]):

                #find what data/timestamps are present in inFile
                time = csvObject[0]['time'][i]
                for k in range(96):
                    #write data to corresponding timestamp
                    if time == tempFrame.index[k]:
                        tempFrame.iloc[k] = csvObject[0].loc[i]
                        #print(''.join(str(type(csvObject[0].loc[i])) + " " + str(csvObject[0].loc[i])))
            #ASK IF SHOULD DELETE TIMESTAMPS AS INDEX OR USE INDEX VALUES INSTEAD OF TIMESTAMPS FOR ROW NAMES
            #ASK IF SHOULD DELETE DOY/CLARIFY WHAT DOY IS SINCE IT IS AWKWARD IN FIRST LINE OF CSV FILE
                # SHOULD MAKE PARSER FOR HDF5 FILES TO RETRIEVE DATA AS WHAT FILE FORMAT?
            tempFrame.index = rowNames

            #append subframe to list for serialization later
            self.subFrames.append(tempFrame)
            a = b
            b +=1
            #use below to check data (empty csv values are NAN)
        
    def findDOY(self):
        #csv dates from dataframe objects
        for i, frame in enumerate(self.subFrames):
            #print(frame['date'].first_valid_index()) #debugging statement
            validIndex = frame['date'].first_valid_index()
            self.DOY.append(frame['date'].iloc[validIndex])

        #metadata dates (which may not necessarily be present in csv dates)
        for i in range(len(self.metaDataObjects)):
            self.metaDataDOY.append(self.metaDataObjects[i][0])


    def appendToFCObject(self):
        #APPEND SUBFRAME TO FCObject array according to DOY (if not subframe present already, then create)
        try:
            from fluxCalculationObject import FCObject
        except:
            print("File not found. Make sure fluxCalculationObject.py is in the same directory.")
            return
        
        #FCObject constructor: def __init__(self, date , dataFrames = [], metaData = None):
        FCObjectDates = [] #to verify/keep track of what dates are already present in self.FCObjects array
        #add entries that were made from csv files into FCOBJECTS array
        for i in range(len(self.subFrames)):
            object = FCObject(self.DOY[i])
            object.addDataFrames(self.subFrames[i])
            if self.DOY[i] not in FCObjectDates:
                FCObjectDates.append(self.DOY[i])
                self.FCObjects.append(object)
            else:
                #iterate through fcobject array to find same date if DOY entry already is present
                for k, item in enumerate(self.FCObjects):
                    if self.DOY[i] == item.date:
                        dataFrame = self.subFrames[i]
                        self.FCObjects[k].addDataFrames(dataFrame)
        
        #add entries that were made from .txt files into FCOBJECTS array
        for i in range(len(self.metaDataObjects)):
            object = FCObject(self.metaDataDOY[i], metaData = self.metaDataObjects[i])
            if self.metaDataDOY[i] not in FCObjectDates:
                FCObjectDates.append(self.DOY[i])
                self.FCObjects.append(object)
            else:
                #iterate through fcobject array to find same date if DOY entry already is present
                for k, item in enumerate(self.FCObjects):
                    if self.metaDataDOY[i] == item.date:
                        metaData = self.metaDataObjects[i][1]
                        self.FCObjects[k].setMetaData(metaData)
    
    def exportFCObjects(self):
        #use record array
            #have to find data types for each column
        #print(testArray)
        object = self.FCObjects[28].dataFrames[0]
        #print(object.columns)
        date = self.FCObjects[28].date.replace("/", "_")

        npArray = object.to_records(index = True)
        print(npArray.dtype)
        
        #for i in range(96):
        #    series = object.iloc[:,i]
        #    #print(series)
        #    series.to_hdf('data.h5', key = self.FCObjects[28].date)\

        #columnNames = data.dtype
        #print(columnNames)
        #f = h5py.File('trial.h5','w')
        #f.create_dataset(self.FCObjects[28].date, data = data)



        #print(type(ser1))
        #hdf = pd.HDFStore("test.h5", 'w')
        #for i in range(len(self.FCObjects)):
        #    for object in self.FCObjects.dataFrames:
        #        hdf.append(str(self.FCObject[i].date), object, format='table', index = False )
        
        ##print(object.dataFrames[1])
        ##print(len(object.dataFrames))
        ##print(type(object.dataFrames[1]))
        ##print(type(object.date))
        #tempStr = object.date.replace("/","_")
        #object.setDate(tempStr)
        #store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
        #store.append(object.date, object.dataFrames[0])
        #store.close()
        #object.dataFrames[0].to_string()
        #object.dataFrames[0].to_csv(''.join(object.date + ".csv"), index = True)
        #object.dataFrames[0].to_hdf("test.h5", object.date, mode='w', format='table')
        #print(pd.read_hdf('test.h5'))
        #hdf.append(object.date, object.dataFrames[1],format='table', data_columns=True, append=True)

        #hdf.close()


                        



    #test/debugging function that exports dataframes as csv
    def exportSubFrames(self):
        outFileNames = []
        for index, object in enumerate(self.csvObjects):
            outFileNames.append(object[3])
        i = 0
        for object in self.subFrames:
            object.to_csv((str(i) + "test.csv"), index = True)
            i += 1
        


    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileNames = []
    for index, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
        #print("Argument #{} is {}".format(index,arg))
        fileNames.append(arg)
    fileNames.remove("csvParser.py")
    
    csvObject = csvParser(fileNames)
    csvObject.createDataFrames()
```

fluxCalculationObject.py

````
class FCObject:
    def __init__(self, date ,dataFrames = [], metaData = 'There is no metadata for this data at this time.'):
        self.dataFrames, self.metaData, self.date = [], metaData, date

    def addDataFrames(self, dataFrame):
        self.dataFrames.append(dataFrame) 
        #print(len(self.dataFrames))

    def setMetaData(self, metaData):
        self.metaData += metaData

    def setDate(self, date):
        self.date = date
    ```
````

Comment: Please describe the data flow and provide example code. How does the data flow from .CSV to HDF5? FYI, this can be done with NumPy `genfromtxt()` to read and create a numpy `recarray`, then write the array with h5py `create_dataset()`. There are multiple examples on Stackoverflowof this procedure.

Comment: Data flow: multiple csv files that include data from multiple DOYs that is unsorted -> read in data and sort/sync according to DOY and timestamps in table format -> write tables to hdf5 file. I will have to add in metadata for each DOY eventually too, but I think that will be much easier to figure out... All I am trying to figure out to do right now is make sure the table is written correctly in the hdf5 file. As of now, I am trying to use a dataframe object to store/format the table, but I guess having multiple data types within the dataframe doesn't mix too well with the hdf5 stuff...

Comment: I don't work with Pandas, so can't help with dataframes. HDF5 supports mixed (compound) datatypes. I use them frequently with pytables and h5py. Regarding metadata, you probably want to save them as attributes on the associated HDF5 object (file, group or dataset).